# Find the particular solution given the auxiliary conditions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $z=f(x+cy)+g(x-cy)$ where $c$ is a constant and the functions $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable.

Deduce the solution of the equation subject to the auxiliary conditions $$z(x,0)=x \text{ and } z_y(x,0)=c \text{ for every } x\in\mathbb{R}$$

I have used the given conditions and concluded that $f'(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=0.$ I recognise that this tells me that $g(x)=c$ and that $f(x)=x+c,$ I'm not sure what to do with that though.

I also know that the correct answer is $z(x,y)=x+cy.$

Comment: pretty sure it should be $z = f(x+cy) + g(x-cy)$

Comment: @WillJagy Good point, I've made an edit.